# hive doesn't insert rows when passing parameters from text though it runs

Tags: parameters, hive

I am trying to pass parameters from a text file on linux to a hive script by doing this:

The content of the text file is:

$emp_code='PRD10' 
$location= 'USA'

I need to use these variable to pass into this hive sql. The contents of the script are:

!cat location of file/empdetails.txt;

insert into emp_pay_detail as select * from empinfo where empcode = '${hiveconf:emp_code}' and elocation = '${hiveconf:location}';

The idea is to pass different parameters from a text file from linux

I try to run this using the following command:

hive -hiveconf emp_code -hiveconf location -f employeedet.sql

The script runs but doesn't insert any rows

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a hive directives input file:

```
set emp_code=PRD10;
set location=USA;
```

And load it using `hive -i input.txt -f employeedet.sql`

If you want to specify more than one location: `set location=USA,UK`, you would need to change the conditions in your query to: `array_contains(split('${hiveconf:location}',','), elocation)`

Full query:

```
insert into emp_pay_detail as select * from empinfo where 
  array_contains(split('${hiveconf:emp_code}',','), empcode) and
  array_contains(split('${hiveconf:location}',','), elocation);
```

Comment: That works well for single string inputs, is it possible to multiple parameters like location=USA,UK, etc. When I try using multiple parameters, doesn't insert the rows

Comment: @Venkat That's because it's a different use case and you would need to change the query for that to use the `IN` keyword. `location IN (${hiveconf:location})` would support multiple parameters

Comment: I did change the query as location IN ('${hiveconf:location}') and input file as set location=USA,UK; but doesn't insert any rows

Comment: Try making it work without the params... the condition should look like `location in ('USA','UK')`

Comment: It does work when run directly in the query like location in('USA', 'UK');

Comment: It seems that the variable was missing apostrophes... try `set location="'USA','UK'"`

Comment: Another option is to keep `set location=USA,UK` and change the condition to `array_contains(split(${hiveconf:location},','), location)`

Comment: Tried using as set location=USA,UK and changed query to location  = array_contains(split{$hiveconf:location},','), location)

Comment: try `array_contains(split('${hiveconf:location}',','), location)`

Comment: Already tried that, throws NoViableAltException(-1@[])  FAILED: ParseException line 1:71 cannot recognize input near '<EOF>' '<EOF>' '<EOF>'

Comment: I guess that was due to commented out lines in the script, it runs and creates the table but doesn't insert the rows

Comment: It works for me... I edited the answer with what worked for me. Make sure that there are no spaces between `USA` and `UK` in `set location=USA,UK`

Comment: please edit your question and post the exact commands that you are running as well as a sample of `empinfo`

Comment: @Venkat If you found my answer helpful, please consider accepting it

Comment: Yes, it has been useful to me

Comment: @Venkat Accepting means clicking the green check mark near the answer :)